# How to run java code (.class) using php and display on the same web page

Tags: java, php, html

I am trying to run a java program using php script.

First, php displays a form where users input two values: Price and Sales Tax Rate.
Next, it extracts the values and passes it to a java program (precompiled as .class file).

I am uncertain as to where the output is printed if at all the java code is working. My ultimate goal is to display the result to the user in an html page.

I upload my file contents to my web server and try to run it from there.

## update:

How can I use shell_exec or exec to run java code? I need to pass the parameters (price, salesTax) to shell_exec. Where is the returned output stored?

**PHP code:**

```
> <?php
> 
> $salesTaxForm = <<<SalesTaxForm
> 
> <form action="SalesTaxInterface.php" method="post">
> 
>    Price (ex. 42.56):<br>
> 
>    <input type="text" name="price" size="15" maxlength="15"
> value=""><br>
> 
>    Sales Tax rate (ex. 0.06):<br>
> 
>    <input type="text" name="tax" size="15" maxlength="15"
> value=""><br>
> 
>    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Calculate!">
> 
>    </form>
> 
> SalesTaxForm;
> 
> if (! isset($submit)) :
> 
>    echo $salesTaxForm;
> 
> else :    $salesTax = new Java("SalesTax");
> 
>    $price = (double) $price;    $tax = (double) $tax;
> 
>    print $salesTax->SalesTax($price, $tax);
> 
> endif;
> 
> ?>
```

**Java Code:**

> ```
> import java.util.*;
> import java.text.*;
>
> public class SalesTax {
> public String SalesTax(double price, double salesTax) 
> {
>
>     double tax = price * salesTax;
>
>     NumberFormat numberFormatter;
>
>     numberFormatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
>
>     String priceOut = numberFormatter.format(price);
>
>     String taxOut = numberFormatter.format(tax);
>
>     numberFormatter = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();
>
>     String salesTaxOut = numberFormatter.format(salesTax);
>
>     String str = "A sales Tax of " + salesTaxOut +
>
>                  " on " + priceOut + " equals " + taxOut + ".";
>
>     return str;
>
>     }
>
> }
> ```

Comment: maybe you can have a look at the PHP-Java bridge. http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

shell-exec executes the comand that you pass to it. To use this, you have to add a Main method  to your class, and pass the properties like arguments in the comand line, so at the end it should look like this:

This is code that you have to execute on php

```
  $output = shell_exec('java SalesTax 10.0 20.0');
```

Where **SalesTax** is your java class, **10.0** is the first argument, and **20.0** the second.

Your main method should be something like this

```
public static void main(String args[]){
   double price = Double.valueOf(args[0]);
   double salesTax = Double.valueOf(args[1]);
   String output = SalesTax(price,salesTax);
   System.out.println(output);
}
```

It's a very simple implementation, you should still add validations and some other stuff, but I think that it's the main idea. Maybe it should be easier to just port it to php.

I hope that you find this helpful. :)

Comment: That was very helpful. I didn't even have the main method previously. Thank you! Yet, php still doest print the output to the html page. nor do i find it in the console. How can I check whether php found the answer or not? Thanks so much for your help

Comment: When i used this on crontab/in url it is not working only on command line is working...

Comment: If you just copied the code as it is it's probably failing because you used relative paths instead of absolute ones. Try changing shell_exec('java YourJavaFile args') to shell_exec('java /full/path/to/yourYourJavaFile args')

Answer (score 0):

I'm no PHP expert, but there are a few ways you could do this:

- Use something like [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) or make a [system call](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php)
- [expose your java logic through a webservice](http://dropwizard.codahale.com/getting-started/)
- Don't do it all! If your posted code is all that's going on, just rewrite the formatting stuff in php or write the whole thing in java.
- [probably some other weird way](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/)

So once you choose a path for your server side stuff, if you want to display the results without a page reload, you will want to use some javascript and most likely some [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or maybe some [`jQuery('.target-area').load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Comment: I cannot modify anything on the server other than place my files there since I don't know much about it. Will the php-java bridge work without having to modify the server? Also, yes the code I have posted is all that I am trying to do. If this basic thing works, then I can implement something further. I would like to try shell_exec and I tried doing something like this: shell_exec(java SalesTax.class); This still doesn't give me any result. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The other thing I realized is how do I send the parameters taken from the user (price, salesTax) using shell_exec to the java code? and where would the output be stored?

Comment: `shell_exec` takes a string and returns the result of the command, but I think you should just write all of it in php at this point.