# run a java class file using php

Tags: java, php

I have java class file **(server.class)** I want to run this file to client machine using php.

**My approach**

1. download the file from server to client machine
2. run this file in client machine
3. close the cmd and delete the file after on pressing another button

**tell me my approach is right or I am making it more complex.If it is complex the then suggest me what is the right approach?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run java code (.class) using php and display on the same web page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17375308/how-to-run-java-code-class-using-php-and-display-on-the-same-web-page)

Comment: What are you trying to do with the Java Class. Elaborate more on the requirement side.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot run programs on a client's machine.  You can provide a download link and instructions on how to run it.

If you want to avoid the client having to click a download button, all I can think of is implementing server.class as an applet inside a web page or maybe using webstart, but I don't know much about webstart, and either way the client will go through a process of agreeing to run the java code.

Also, it sounds like some shady, shady stuff you're attempting to do.  I hope you're not trying to run something on a person's computer without them knowing.  If that is the case... I WILL find you :P

Comment: No no I am trying to run a audio class which will listen the a mic from mobile.